# Silent crash when creating a NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

```
Profile *profile = [[Profile alloc] init];

NSLog(@"badgeId is %@", badgeId);

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[profile getAuthenticationToken], @"auth_token", badgeId, "badge_id", title, "title", nil];
```

it silently crashes after returning the method getAuthenticationToken (which returns a string). It seems to go to a memory reference then crash. the println on badgeId on the line before returns the following:

```
badgeId is 97
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One problem is that a C string like `"badge_id"` is not a good NSDictionary key. Use an NSString object such as `@"badge_id"`.

Answer (score 2):

Keys of a dictionary have to be objects that implement the NSCopying-Protocol. C strings are no (Objective-C) objects and therefore do not implement NSCopying.